# How to build a model correctly for such a task?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

There is a simple model with posts and users.
How to show user # 1 all posts without his comments? (not using the not-in operand)

```
{ user:
    user1 : {
       somedata...
    },
    user2 : {
       somedata...
    },
}


{ post: 
    post1 : {
       title: 'hi',
       text : 'Good post',
       comment: {
          user1 : {
             msg: "my comment"
          }
       }
    },
    post2 : {
       title: 'hi 2',
       text : 'Good post 2',
       
    },
    post3 : {
       title: 'hi 3',
       text : 'Good post 3',
       
    }
}
```

Such a structure for an example task. I can change the structure to any one that can solve my problem.

Comment: Can you screenshots of Firestore structure? I'm not sure if `comment` is a map or a sub-collection.

Comment: I haven’t done the structure yet, because I cannot cope with such a task. That is, I cannot think of a scheme that would allow me to get the request I need. So far, I'm stumped.

Comment: Using the example of an array, I showed the task itself. If a solution needs to change the structure, I will do it.